# How to get total paid value of the cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php-7

I am trying to build up an extension that affiliates with the customer's final paid total and divide the value by 100, in order to give a customer a 1% point.

Answer (score 0):

You can get total paid by below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

$grandTotal = $cartObj->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: did you check it @Gayashan  ?